# How to enlist spring JDBC transaction within a XA-transaction?

Tags: spring, jpa, jdbc, jboss, jta

Using spring's [3.1] SimpleJdbcCall to call a stored procedure in a Oracle db.
Again, there is another transaction using JPA 2.0 [hibernate 3.6.8]. Both of them needs to be committed in a single xa transaction. I would like to use JBoss AS's [7.1.1] transaction manager for JTA.

From my applicationContext.xml >

```
    <!-- injecting jdbc datasource -->
<bean id="CbsTransactionRepository"
    class="com.misl.treasury.cbsIntegration.repository.CbsTransactionRepositoryJDBC">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>



<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/CoreDS"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="treasuryDataSource" jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/TreasuryDS"/>


<!-- JPA entity manager -->
<bean id="treasuryEntityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="treasuryDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/hibernatepersistence.xml" />

</bean>



<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:jboss/UserTransaction" /> 
</bean> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

Now, how to enlist spring jdbc transaction within JTA transaction manager's scope so that I can use declarative @Transactional annotation for data access calls from a single method?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption was as I do not see any links between "datasource" [which is the datasource for Spring JDBC] and transaction manager, I have to do something extra to enforce JDBC transaction to be enlisted in JTA transaction manager. And when I was debugging I also found that spring JDBC transactions were committed as soon as it leaves simpleJDBCCallobject.execute method. And that's why I thought I was doing wrong. Actually, applicationContext configuration was fine. My jndi data sources were not XADatasources! While configuring XADatasources in JBoss AS 7.1, I had to use multiple properties to describe the url [instead of a single URL property] :

```
 <datasources>
 <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TreasuryDS" pool-name="TreasuryDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                    192.168.1.197
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="User">
                    treasury
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="Password">
                    treasury
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                    1521
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                    XE
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DriverType">
                    thin
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                <driver>OracleJDBCDriver</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                    <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>treasury</user-name>
                    <password>treasury</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </xa-datasource>

         <!---
         ...... here goes another XA Datasource .....
         ---->

            <drivers>
                <driver name="OracleJDBCDriver" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
     </datasources>
```